# I want to open an image then a push button becomes enabled in MATLAB. How to?

Tags: matlab

I have following matlab GUI code.

```
clear all;
clc;

win = figure('units','points',...
    'position',[200 250 500 400],...
    'color',[.8 .8 .8],...
    'menubar','none',...
    'resize','off',...
    'numbertitle','off',...
    'name','test window');

menu = uimenu('parent',win,...
    'Label','File');

submenu1 = uimenu('parent',menu,...
    'Label','Open');

submenu2 = uimenu('parent',menu,...
    'Label','Exit',...
    'Callback','close');

frame1 = uicontrol('parent',win,...
    'units','points',...
    'position',[30 170 200 200],...
    'backgroundcolor',[.9 .9 .9],...
    'style','Frame');

recButton = uicontrol('parent',win,...
    'units','points',...
    'position',[90 130 70 30],...
    'style','pushbutton',...
    'string','Button');
```

What I want to do is load an image with Open submenu (submenu1) and then display it inside frame1. I want recButton is disabled by default. After the image is loaded recButton becomes enabled. Can you help me with the code?

Comment: *I want recButton is disabled by default.* should be *I want recButton to be disabled by default.*

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker so I'm not fluent in English. Thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 2):

You should first create the `recButton` control with its [`'Enable'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoiky) set to `'off'`. Then in the [callback](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/uimenu_props.html#bqxrpqb) that's executed for `submenu1` you should re-enable the `recButton` control:

```
set(recButton,'Enable','on');
```

You would just have to make sure that the handle variable `recButton` is available in the callback for `submenu1`.